# Azure Monitor Workbook Query - retrieve data from Azure REST API Synapse Data Plane

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

trying to build a Workbook retrieving data from Azure REST API about [Synapse Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline/get-pipelines-by-workspace), which belongs to another [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/#common-parameters-and-headers) (https://dev.azuresynapse.net) not like Azure Resource Manager API (https://management.azure.com). In Monitor Workbook query there is a special data source "Azure Resource Manager" for Azure RM API, which works perfectly for me since an authentication/authorization is built-in (works in background). However for Synapse Data Plane API (because of another endpoint) is usage of "Custom Endpoint" query data source eventually required. Here the bearer (access) token has to be requested beforehand [separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token) from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token). If I try to implement it through a separate Query it doesn't work because of CORS (see picture attached), not supported by login.microsoftonline.com (the request works probably via AJAX).The same construct for Synapse works very well in Postman.
Can anyone please tell me how can I implement such API Request in the Workbook?

Regards
Ivan

[access token request Query (Error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HazJ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-trivial thing that isn't directly supported in workbooks today.

The way the Azure portal itself does auth between various extensions/resource providers makes for a lot of little details to get cross-auth like this to work.

I'll followup with the Synapse team and see if/how easy this might be for us to implement.  It would require us to write a custom data source in workbooks once that auth is available.  (I *believe* we've already asked for them to possibly expose this data through ARM to get rid of these extra requirements) If you have a concrete scenario/example, can you followup via email?  jgardner @ MS

for your CORS related thing, you *might* be able to get past that error if you go to the headers tab of that screenshot and check the box that removes all the extra headers?  it might be rejecting the CORS request there because of extra headers it doesn't expect?

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much for your reply. The workaround with the check box "don't send correlation headers" didn't work.

Comment: ok, good to know.  you might need to look at the network tab/fiddler to see the exact content/reason why that call was rejected, it might not support being called directly by the portal? ‍♂️  doing these things from postman/etc work because they don't have any CORS requirements since they aren't a browser

Comment: Hi John, on the network tab I see the following message "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/53721*****553/oauth2/token' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". That means to me, that the target  endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com) doesn't support CORS in fact.

Comment: that output in the console would be the browser telling you the response didn't have that content/header, but if you look at the full request/response for the options request, did that request have any content? sometimes the request has details in its response about why it wasn't accepted and didn't contain the header?  i see some other similar questions across github/etc about this specific endpoint and CORS

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to retrieve the configuration data from synapse workspace (triggers, pipelines, linkedServices etc.) using Azure Monitor Workbook custom endpoint (query data source). It is applicable only if your synapse workspace linked to git via Azure DevOps service. In this case you can grab the config information relevant to production environment using Azure DevOps API as follows:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?scopePath={Path}/TemplateForWorkspace.json&version=workspace_publish&download=true&api-version=6.0&Authorization](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/items?scopePath=%7BPath%7D/TemplateForWorkspace.json&version=workspace_publish&download=true&api-version=6.0&Authorization) Basic=BASE64PATSTRING

for that purpose you have to issue a token on the DevOps side. CORS policies are not a problem for such request as it is GET not PUT one

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be based on the assumption, that the synapse workspace configuration will change pretty rarely and its representation in monitoring tool (workbook) will be relevant for the day before (yesterday).
That could be implemented through App Function taking the data in the same way (as described earlier) from synapse workspace REST API and write those in the application log (e.g. with certain tag).
Then the most recent log records can be taken by the workbook (from Application Insights)